# Angular2 karma testing moving systemjs into subdirectory stops evaluation ".js" extension

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I used exactly the same setting found here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html#!#download

Documented here: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

Except that I moved the systemjs.config.js to a sub directory (let's call it "src"), and updated both karma-test-shim.js and karma.conf.js to point to it. So did with systemjs `app: '../app',`

I run `karma start` and it all works except the jasmine test itself, it looks for `base/app/app.component` and returns 404. If I change the import statement to have ".js" like this:
`import { AppComponent } from './app.component.js';`

It works!

That does not happen when systemjs is on the root. What am I missing?

I did not make any changes to `tsconfig.json` in case it matters. Here are the files included in the quick starter:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

the src/systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */

(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: '../app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

The .config/karma.conf.js (moving it into .config does not produce different results)

```
// #docregion
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = 'base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase    = 'testing/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'testing/';       // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'src/systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
     // { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },

      //{ pattern: 'src/systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
      '.config/karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false }
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    // disabled HtmlReporter; suddenly crashing w/ strange socket error
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],//'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

the .config/karma-test-shim.js

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/app/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {

  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: 'base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('src/systemjs.config.js')
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

the app.component.spec.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; // do i have to include .js?

import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

////////  SPECS  /////////////
describe('AppComponent', function () {
  let de: DebugElement;
  let comp: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
  });

  it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined() );

  it('should have expected <h1> text', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const h1 = de.nativeElement;
    expect(h1.innerText).toMatch(/angular/i,
      '<h1> should say something about "Angular"');
  });
});
```

Comment: I just tried again with systemjs as is (without modifiying app: 'app',) and it worked! :/ I don't understand why or how though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many problems found, mainly in paths of files, in karma config and systemjs config, but for the issue of this specific question it was the path of "app" in systemjs

```
app: '../app',
```

Should have been relative to root instead of sub folder

```
app: 'app',
```